# WooCommerce 2.3.13 thankyou filter

Tags: php, woocommerce

`woocommerce_thankyou_order_id` filter hook is not working on a `WooCommerce` environment with version **2.3.13** but works on `WooCommerce` environment version **2.4.13**.

Would the version difference be the problem for the filter hook to not work?

Comment: I don't have version 2.3.13 but look into the file `class-wc-shortcode-checkout.php`... try to see if it has that filter... particularly in `order_received` function... if not, then it's a version problem...

Comment: Yup, it was because of the version difference. The filter was added since the 2.4.5 WooCommerce update